# SQL Server Connection String problem?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Using VB6, SQL Server 2000

I want to connect to others system database.

Code:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                                "Persist Security Info=False; " & _
                                "User ID=" & SQL_Username & "; Password = " & SQL_Password & "; " & _
                                "Initial Catalog=" tmp_table1 ";" & _
                                "Data Source=" & SQL_ServerAddress
```

Values

```
SQL_ServerAddress = 192.11.12.11\SQLEXPRESS
SQL_Username = sa
SQL_Password = sa
```

Unable to connect to others system database

How to get a database from the other system?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to connect"? Is that the error message you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have configured Sql Express to accept remote connections haven't you? Networking protocols are disabled by default in Sql Express and you have to enable them to remotely access the database. You'll need to configure Sql Express to [accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx)

Comment: yep, 90% of times, this is the problem.